# How to import scripts from node_modules folder

Tags: npm, angular, asp.net5

I'm trying to get an ASP5 application to run with Angular 2.0 following a tutorial. After a few steps in I realized it did not work when I try to work on it without an internet connection (I'm usually working on it while I'm sitting in a train). Of course the imports suggested by the tutorial won't work without an internet connection:

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.1/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

Thus, I tried to include the local files from my node_modules folder like this:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

The files exist and are correct. But when I try to debug the project I'll get the following error for all four files: `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement` and when I look at the files via browser, all I receive is files with `Hello World!` written in it. I obviously seem to be missing something but as I've never worked with the whole npm part before, I have no idea why this would happen and after googling for hours nobody else seems to have that problem.

Is it access restriction? Missing JS module? Can anyone explain how I can include files from my node_modules folder in my html?

Comment: What you want to do is use Webpack and let it modularity bundle dependencies and files you need for you.

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.Net 5 /wwwroot is the default root directory for your web application so when you enter:

node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js

its actually searched in the following path:

wwwroot/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js

Although the file exists in the project root i.e.

node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js

But since its not in the web application root, you would see 404 error for these scripts.

The solution is to copy these files to wwwroot folder.

I would suggest writing a gulp task to automatically copy files to wwwroot/script/lib folder

and then you can use them like this:

```
//Sample Gulp file code
var paths = {
    npmSrc: "./node_modules/",
    libTarget: "./wwwroot/lib/"
};

var libsToMove = [
    paths.npmSrc + '/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
    paths.npmSrc + '/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js',
    paths.npmSrc + '/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.min.js',
    paths.npmSrc + '/systemjs/dist/system.js',
    paths.npmSrc + '/rxjs/bundles/rx.min.js',
    paths.npmSrc + '/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js',
    paths.npmSrc + '/angular2/bundles/router.js',
    paths.npmSrc + '/angular2/bundles/http.min.js',
];
```

Then in your html page or view you can use these like this:

```
<script src="~/lib/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/angular2-polyfills.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/system.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/rx.min.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/angular2.dev.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/router.js"></script>
<script src="/lib/http.min.js"></script>
```

You should see a gulp file in the root of your project, if its not there just create a file with name "gulpfile.js" in the root of your project.

I hope this helps :)

Comment: what does "~/" mean in the src property?